# Substitution matrix from cross elasticity

Tags: elasticity

Is there a way to calculate a subsitution matrix from cross elasticy matrix ?

I have 5x5 cross elasticy matirx for 5 SKUs. I am trying to simulate SKUs demand switch in case of price changes.

Answer (score 2):

Lee Cooper's book *Market Share Analysis* has a discussion of "differential cross-elasticities" in the context of full-blown marketing mix models beginning on page 59. Based on that discussion as well as a subsequent discussion on the confounding of substitutability, complementarity and independence (see p. 179++), if all that is available to you is literally just a two-mode matrix, you don't have enough information to do what you would like to do, at least with any hope of being accurate about it.

What additional information do you have available regarding this matrix?

http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/lee.cooper/MCI_Book/BOOKI2010.pdf

Comment: thanks for references, I also have price elasticity and numeric distribution elasticity for SKUs. I've calculated all these elasticities with a multiplicative power model. which is like vol_sku1 = b0 * price^bp * nd^bn * vol_sku2^s2 * vol_sku3^s3 * vol_sku4^s4 * vol_sku5^s5. I used nlxb to solve this equaiton with nlmrt on R